# Which is the best SE to ask about the meaning behind a movie title adapated from a novel?

Tags: discussion, scope, questions, specific-question

I want to ask about the significance of the title *Primal Fear*.

I've only seen the movie, but I know it's based on a novel of the same name.

Film adaptations can differ substantially from their source material, so maybe the film supports a different meaning than the novel. Different or not, the straightforward answer would be "the movie takes its title from the novel," which is (probably) factually true but obviously uninteresting.

So, where is the best place to ask this question? Movies.SE, or Literature.SE? Or somewhere else?

Answer (score 7):

I can't answer which site would give you the best answer.

However Movies & TV does allow answers to include content from the original work. So it is not unreasonable for the question to ask that the answer goes deeper than "it was the title of the book".